# Horizontal recyclerView inside item in vertical recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, asynctaskloader

I have an issue in my app ... i am using ramotion.foldingcell library and using it to make list by recyclerView and when tap in cell of list it open another recyclerView but in horizontal ... i get data from json and usin AsynctaskLoader 
to load data .... my problem is when the horizontal recyclerView in onbindingView it get all list of data every item in vertical list not in specific row .... every row should have 7 item not in same as other rows

[image from activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4UyK.png)

code of custom vertical list :

```
package com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.R;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.activities.Projects;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.adapters.ListOFProjects;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemsForCells {

    private Bitmap image;
    private ArrayList<ProjectsList> listOFProjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public ItemsForCells(){

    }

    public ArrayList<ProjectsList> getListOFProjects() {
        return listOFProjects;
    }

    public void setListOFProjects(ArrayList<ProjectsList> listOFProjects) {
        this.listOFProjects = listOFProjects;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

code of custom horizontal list :

```
 package com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProjectsList  {

    Bitmap imageOfProject;
    String dis;

    public ProjectsList(Bitmap imageOfProject, String dis) {
        this.imageOfProject = imageOfProject;
        this.dis = dis;
    }

    public Bitmap getImageOfProject() {
        return imageOfProject;
    }

    public String getDis() {
        return dis;
    }
}
```

code for horizontal recyclerView :

```
        package com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.adapters;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
    import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.R;
    import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.activities.Projects;
    import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list.ItemsForCells;
    import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list.ProjectsList;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ListOFProjects extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListOFProjects.MyViewHolder> {
        private static final String TAG = "ListOFProjects";
        private ArrayList<ProjectsList> projectsLists;
        private Context context;



        public ListOFProjects(Context context, ArrayList<ProjectsList> projectsLists) {
            this.projectsLists = projectsLists;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.items_projects, parent, false);
            final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

            return myViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final ProjectsList list = projectsLists.get(position);

            holder.disOfProject.setText(list.getDis());
            Bitmap bitmap = list.getImageOfProject();

            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.shape);

            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(bitmap)
                    .apply(requestOptions.centerCrop().override(500, 450))
                    .into(holder.imageOfProject);

            Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + projectsLists.size());


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return projectsLists.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private ImageView imageOfProject;
            private TextView disOfProject;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageOfProject = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_projects_list);
                disOfProject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameofproject);
            }
        }

    }
```

code for virtical recyclerView :

```
package com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.CustomItemClickListener;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.CustomLinearLayoutManager;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.R;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.activities.Projects;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list.ItemsForCells;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list.ProjectsList;
import com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class CellsProjectsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CellsProjectsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "CellsProjectsAdapter";
    private Context context;
    private List<ItemsForCells> itemsForCells;

    public CellsProjectsAdapter(Context context, List<ItemsForCells> itemsForCells) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemsForCells = itemsForCells;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cells, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ItemsForCells items = itemsForCells.get(position);

        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + itemsForCells.size());
        try {
            holder.titleImageView.setImageBitmap(items.getImage());
            //ArrayList<ProjectsList> projects = items.getListOFProjects();
            ListOFProjects projectsList = new ListOFProjects(context, items.getListOFProjects());
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager =
                    new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(projectsList);
            projectsList.notifyDataSetChanged();
            holder.recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

            holder.foldingCell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    holder.foldingCell.toggle(false);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsForCells.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView titleImageView;
        FoldingCell foldingCell;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titleImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image_cell);
            foldingCell = (FoldingCell) itemView.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_cell);

        }
    }
}
```

activity for display this :

```
package com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.activities;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.CustomItemClickListener;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.R;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.adapters.CellsProjectsAdapter;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.adapters.ListOFProjects;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list.ItemsForCells;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.list.ProjectsList;
import com.example.m_elblasy.psedv2.loaders.ProjectsLoader;
import com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Projects extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<ItemsForCells>> {
    private static final String TAG = "Projects";
    //private static final String JSON_PROJECTS_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/69w78";
    private static final String JSON_PROJECTS_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/pc04g";
    static CellsProjectsAdapter cellsProjectsAdapter;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<ItemsForCells> data;
    private static final int PROJECTS_LOADER_ID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_projects);

        data = new ArrayList<>();

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_item_projects);


        cellsProjectsAdapter = new CellsProjectsAdapter(this, data);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            getLoaderManager().initLoader(PROJECTS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public Loader<List<ItemsForCells>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new ProjectsLoader(this, JSON_PROJECTS_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<ItemsForCells>> loader, List<ItemsForCells> itemsForCells) {

        if (itemsForCells != null && !itemsForCells.isEmpty()) {
            data.clear();
            data.addAll(itemsForCells);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(cellsProjectsAdapter);
            cellsProjectsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<ItemsForCells>> loader) {
        loader.forceLoad();

    }

}
```